# Increasing labelling size in a ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Labeled[dataY[[i]], i], {i, 1, 
   Length[dataY]}], Filling -> Bottom, 
 AxesLabel -> {"O", "W", "C"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

Is there a way to increase the size of the labelling of the points in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `Style[]` to `i`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Labeled[dataY[[i]], Style[i,16]], {i, 1, 
   Length[dataY]}], Filling -> Bottom, 
 AxesLabel -> {"O", "W", "C"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

Comment: Many thanks Lee ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the option [`LabelStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelStyle.html). To keep the tick and axes labels unchanged add the option `AxesStyle -> FontSize -> Medium`:

```
dataY = RandomReal[10, {10, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[Table[Labeled[dataY[[i]], i], {i, 1, Length[dataY]}], 
  LabelStyle -> Large, 
  AxesStyle -> FontSize -> Medium, 
  Filling -> Bottom, 
  AxesLabel -> {"O", "W", "C"}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

[image]